# jQuery colorbox plugin resize callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, colorbox

I have an ASP.NET MVC application and I am using two JQuery plugins: colorbox and jcrop. My issue is with the colorbox resize function. After I load the content into the colorbox I call the resize function to resize colorbox to fit its contents better. This works great except for the fact that immediately after that I add the jcrop plugin to the mix. Jcrop fires slightly before the colorbox resize function finishes. Because of this, it distorts the data for jcrop. This causes the crop tool to jump on the initial move, as in this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Xg84D/12/

Notice how in the above example the crop selector jumps on the initial move, as in this question:

[jQuery Jcrop setSelect shows visually, but when clicked to move, it jumps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682243/jquery-jcrop-setselect-shows-visually-but-when-clicked-to-move-it-jumps)

The only way I have found to stop this, is to wrap the jcrop bit in a `setTimeout()` and delay the code for 1 second to ensure the resize is finished before the code fires, as in this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Xg84D/13/

Now when you drag the crop area it does not jump around at first. Using `setTimeout()` is definitely a hack that I don't like so I'd like to know if anyone has any suggestions. If only `jQuery.colorbox.resize()` accepted a callback function on its settings object.

Thanks!

Comment: I can't see the problem with [http://jsfiddle.net/Xg84D/12/](http://jsfiddle.net/Xg84D/12/). Can you provide another sample?

Comment: In the first example start to drag the crop square. It will jump toward the bottom right of the image. Then begin to drag the crop square in the second one, you will notice it is smooth as butter, with no jumping. It only jumps once in the first example after the initial drag, but it's enough to be annoying.

Comment: Ok! Got it! I can see the problem ...

Comment: It happens because the jQuery.colorbox.resize() is not done performing the resize when the jcrop code runs. Delaying it by a second is usually enough to ensure that the resize finishes, but I don't like it. In slower javascript engines the resize may still not be done after one second, but any longer and the wait for jcrop to load becomes annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the development version of colorbox at GitHub, there's a commit that solves your problem.
See it [here](https://github.com/jasonmoo/colorbox/commit/91de326355a51cfcf49762a41f97479f6fc9b9a1#diff-0)

I think that you should edit the function `resize` in jquery.colorbox.js file to accept a callback parameter. AS the link suggest.

```
@@ -450,7 +450,7 @@    
     });    
   };     

-  publicMethod.resize = function (options) {    
+  publicMethod.resize = function (options, loadedCallback) {    
     if (open) {    
       options = options || {};

@@ -475,7 +475,7 @@

       }

       $loaded.css({height: settings.h});           

-      publicMethod.position(settings.transition === "none" ? 0 : settings.speed);    
+      publicMethod.position(settings.transition === "none" ? 0 : settings.speed, loadedCallback);
     }
   };
```

Good luck!

Comment: Or, maybe you can download it [here](https://github.com/jasonmoo/colorbox/zipball/91de326355a51cfcf49762a41f97479f6fc9b9a1) (zipped)

Comment: @Alex, can I give you a tip? Try to avoid using the JQuery selector for the same target multiple times. Instead `jQuery('#cropTool')` n times, use: `var cropTool = jQuery('#cropTool');`and use `cropTool` var to retrive the values. Att

Comment: Right, but this was just a sample. I tapped it out without really thinking. Trust me, I'm much more anal about code readability in my actual implementations.